# Rounding off complex and real numbers in lua

Tags: function, lua, arguments, rounding

I want a round function for complex numbers. It is assumed that complex numbers will always be written in a+bi form where a and b are real numbers. I want a function similar to the following function.

```
function round(num, numDecimalPlaces)
  local mult = 10^(numDecimalPlaces or 0)
  return math.floor(num * mult + 0.5) / mult
end
```

This function round offs real numbers. What exactly I want is this.

```
 round(2.784,2) --will result into 2.78
    round(2.78655,3) --will result into 2.787
    round(2.784+3.1245i,2) --will result into 2.78+3.12i
    round("2.7885+3.1246i",3) --will result into 2.789+3.125i
    round("3.1246i",2) --will result into 3.12i
```

Comment: `round(3.1246i,2)` that's not valid Lua code. Are you perhaps using GSL-Shell?

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer - `round(3.1246i,2) that's not valid Lua code` - It's valid LuaJIT code